# ASP.Net MVC and using Linq to Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm following an MVC 5 tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dashboard-application-with-asp-net-mvc-5-and-jquery/

but the Author left out 1 of the features - the middle panel - "Orders" (which is the orders for all customers). It has a View Details link but no code and partial view is displayed when clicked.

[image]

So I'm trying to do create that partial view but having trouble with writing the Linq To Entities.

I am trying for just a partial view that is like a header/multi detail:

CustomerName CustomerImage
  OrderDate
     Quantity ProductType, ProductName, ProductImage
  OrderDate
     Quantity ProductType, ProductName, ProductImage
CustomerName CustomerImage
    OrderDate
     Quantity ProductType, ProductName, ProductImage

Here is the ViewModels I created to represent the above:

```
public class OrderDetailsViewModel
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductImage { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerOrdersViewModel
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerImage { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderDetailsViewModel> OrderDetailsViewModel{ get;
    set; }
}
```

Here is the DbContext and the models that the Author created:

DbContext:

```
public class DashboardContext : DbContext
{
    // Constructor - inherits the base constructor.
    public DashboardContext() : base("DashboardOrder")
    {
    }

    public IDbSet<Customer> CustomerSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Order> OrderSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Product> ProductSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<OrderDetails> OrderDetailSet { get; set; }
}
```

Customer:

```
public class Customer : IEntity
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Orders = new List<Order>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPhone { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCountry { get; set; }
    public string CustomerImage { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

IEntity:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Order:

```
public class Order : IEntity
{
    public Order()
    {
        OrderDetail = new List<OrderDetails>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetails> OrderDetail { get; set; }
}
```

OrderDetails:

```
public class OrderDetails : IEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Quatity { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Product:

```
public class Product : IEntity
{
    public Product()
    {
        OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetails>();
    }

    // Auto-implemented properties.
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public string ProductImage { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Action Method in the DashboardController I was attempting to write.

I believe I want to read the Order Model which in turn has reference to the Customer and a list of Orders which in turn has a reference to the list of OrderDetail which has reference to the Product.

But I'm having a hard time with the "Linq to SQL" to get the data in the lists in the models to create my ViewModel to flatten it out and pass to my partial view as a list.

```
    public ActionResult GetCustomerOrdersDetails()
    {
        List<CustomerOrdersViewModel> customerOrders = null;

        using (DashboardContext _context = new DashboardContext())
        {
            // Using LINQ TO SQL and deferred execution via the "ToList".
            customerOrders = (from o in _context.OrderSet
                              select new CustomerOrdersViewModel
                              {
                                  CustomerName = o.Customer.CustomerName,
                                  CustomerImage = o.Customer.CustomerImage,
                                  OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                                  -- Here I need to process the list of Orders which in turn has a reference to the list of OrderDetail which has
                                  reference to the Product.
                                  ProductType = ?,
                                  ProductName = ?,
                                  ProductImage = ?,
                                  Quantity = ?,
                              }).ToList();
        }

        return PartialView("~/Views/Dashboard/GetCustomerOrdersDetails.cshtml", customerOrders);
    }
```

Comment: `Order` contains a collection of `OrderDetails` (which in turn contains `Product`), therefor your view model needs to contain a collection property for an `OrderDetailsViewModel` containing properties fro the `Product` details and `Quantity` (and you would use a `.GroupBy()` on the `Customer` property of `Order`)

Comment: Ya lost me...when you state "your view model" are you referring to the CustomerOrdersViewModel I stated I created above? If so, I created a OrderProducts class that contains the Product details and Quantity properties (4). I then added that as a collection to the CustomerOrdersViewModel. The list I'm trying to create. But that does not  make sense to me. Further I don't see how to write Linq to Sql to that with using a ,GroupBy().

Comment: Yes, I was referring to that view model. But (from your last edit), why would you want a 'flat' structure (for which you would need a `.SelectMany()` clause) that just means you keep repeating the customer name and image? Surely it would be better to group by the customer and for each customer (say as a heading), include their product details (say in a table for each customer)

Comment: Also what is the `string type` parameter in the method for - you never use it.

Comment: The string type was from a copy and paste. I removed it. Ideally I do not want the flat structure. I want what you suggest but was trying to just keep it simple for now as I'm new to Link to SQL. I now get what you means so I will post it above. Then I will need help with the retrieval.

Comment: In Linq to Entities - `var model = db.OrderSet.GroupBy(x => new { Name = Customer.CustomerName, Image = Customer.CustomerImage }).Select(x => new CustomerOrdersViewModel
{ CustomerName = x.Key.Name, CustomerImage = x.Key.Image, OrdersProduct = x.Select(y => new OrdersProduct{ ProductName = y.ProductName, etc }) }).ToList();`

Comment: using (DashboardContext _context = new DashboardContext()) {customerOrders = _context.OrderSet.GroupBy(x => new { Name = Customer.CustomerName, Image = Customer.CustomerImage, Date = OrderDate }).Select(x => new CustomerOrdersViewModel { CustomerName = x.Key.Name,CustomerImage = x.Key.Image, OrderDate = x.Key.Order,                                          OrderDetailsViewModel = x.Select(y => new OrderDetailsViewModel { Quantity = y.Quantity, ProductType = y.ProductType, ProductName = y.ProductName, ProductImage = y.ProductImage})}).ToList();}

Comment: Sorry for changing things midstream...but i put the above to your original suggestion. So I modified your Linq to Entities. But getting squiggly red lines under Customer. and OrderDate.Can't seem to resolve. I don't see why it is even doing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162855/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user3020047).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need a `.GroupBy()` clause to group the records by `CustomerName`, `CustomerImage` and `OrderDate`. Then because `OrderDetail` is a collection proeprty, you need a `.SelectMany()` to 'flatten that collection before projecting the result to your `OrderDetailsViewModel` model.

```
List<CustomerOrdersViewModel> model = db.OrderSet
    .GroupBy(x => new { Name = x.Customer.CustomerName, Image = x.Customer.CustomerImage, Date = x.Date })
    .Select(x => new CustomerOrdersViewModel
    {
        CustomerName = x.Key.Name, 
        CustomerImage = x.Key.Image,
        OrderDate = x.Key.Date,
        OrderDetailsViewModel = x.SelectMany(y => y.OrderDetail).Select(y => new OrderDetailsViewModel
        {
            ProductName = y.Product.ProductName,
            Quantity = y.Quantity,
            ProductType = y.Product.ProductType,
            ProductImage = y.Product.ProductImage
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
return PartialView(model);
```

Then in the view you can use nested loops to display the details of each order

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomerOrdersViewModel>
....
@foreach(var order in Model)
{
    .... // display details of customer name, date etc
    @order.CustomerName
    foreach(var item in order.OrderDetailsViewModel)
    {
        .... // display details of product, quantity etc for each order
        @item.ProductName
```